# Pipeline Gstreamer RTSP file sinking with big delay

Tags: delay, gstreamer-1.0, mkfifo, rtsp-client

I prepared a IP camera with Gstremer on RTSP and it seems to online and real time, with command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.138:554/axis-media/media.amp ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

it is excellent and delay for displaying about **40 ms(milliseconds)**.

If i delete `sync=false` end of `autovideosink` it is displaying with **2 seconds** delay.

Now I want Sync RTSP streaming on a file. At first I create a pipe by `mkfifo file.ts` in `/tmp`and then use of :

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.138:554/axis-media/media.amp ! rtph264depay ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=file.ts
```

it works and sync RTSP with `ts` format and `h264` codec correctly. I can play it with `mplayer file.ts` or `gst-play-1.0 file.ts` successfully but has **2 seconds** delay!

I tried use of `sync=false` or `autovideosink` but i get error or doesn't effect.

How can I decrease delay in file sinking?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found issue 
Default valve of Jitter Buffer in Official Gstreamer documentation is 200ms but in reality is 2 seconds.

> “latency” guint
>   The maximum latency of the jitterbuffer. Packets will be kept in the buffer for at most this time.
>   Flags : Read /  Write
>   Default value : 200
>   [Here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpjitterbuffer.html?gi-language=c#rtpjitterbuffer:latency)

so I can increase delay to 400ms with command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc latency = 0 location=rtsp://192.168.1.138:554/axis-media/media.amp ! rtph264depay ! mpegtsmux ! filesink  location=file.ts
```

also 400ms delay is for mkfifo, so Named Pipe is not good solution for real time application.

Comment: Amir, could you elaborate on the 400ms delay for mkfifo? And how did you manage to avoid a named pipe then?

Comment: I've found the solution (at least works for me) to the introduced latency problem. Use `fdsink` instead of `filesink`.